# Bottom bracket repair stand experience

Tags: product-rec, repair, repair-stand

Does anyone have direct experience with the [ParkTool Team Race Stand](http://www.parktool.com/product/team-race-stand-prs-20) or **other brands/models** of bottom bracket repair stands? If so, do you like it and why? A good answer for me will include the following:

- Describe your personal experiences using this type/model of stand.
- What characteristics of the Team Race Stand make it better/worse than the alternatives?
- What other repair stands like the Team Race Stand have you tried?
- What is the Team Race Stand best at? What is it worst at?

I'm shopping for a new repair stand and very interested in the ParkTool. I have a 20 year old folding ParkTool stand that clamps onto the frame and it's not suitable for my newer bicycles. In my household we have 3 road bikes (2 carbon), 2 commuter bikes and 1 mountain bike.

The reviews for the ParkTool stand are generally good, but unfortunately the product is not heavily reviewed; and none of the local shops stock this model so that I can get a first hand look.

***Note:*** I am familiar with and have used several models of "seat-clamp" repair stands, so I don't need a description of how those work.

[image: ParkTool Team Race Stand]

Comment: Do you have specific concerns? Asking "do you like it and why?" isn't really an answerable question.

Comment: Don't the online reviews come from people with direct experience?

Comment: @Neil - If I asked you, "What do you like about your panniers (or whatever), and why?" you would be able to give me an answer. Correct? So, my question is answerable.

Comment: According to, http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/276/do-we-go-shopping shopping questions are acceptable. I am asking: about personal experiences using this product and the characteristics of this product that make it better/or worse than the alternatives. Zenbike is off to a good start.

Comment: @Jefromi - This product is not heavily reviewed, so I was attempting to increase the sample size. I thought that asking the question on a bicycling Q & A site might work.

Comment: @wdy - You'd still be asking me for an opinion. Questions that ask for opinions can have an unlimited number of answers, and are not proper questions here.

Comment: @Neil - I am a bicyclist. I have a question regarding an issue I'd like to solve. So far, Zenbike, a high rep, knowledgable user has provided me with a decent and useful answer that will help me make a more intelligent decision for a likely purchase. Of course it's his opinion, but it's a knowledgable opinion.

Comment: @wdy - Your edit is a big improvement. I still take exception to "Describe your personal experiences" - it's polling the community and asking for anecdotes. However, it is a very small aspect of the question. Have removed my downvote.

Comment: @Neil - Take a look at "Do We Go Shopping" in meta and towards the middle of Freiheit's answer. I lifted my question edits directly from there.

Comment: @wdy - That's a really good point, thanks; I had missed that! I'm [taking this to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3307890#3307890).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 types of repair stands. The bottom bracket version you pictured is compact, stable, and travels well. It is a good stand if you are using it occasionally for your own maintenance. Downside: You can only work on one end of the bike at a time. That makes it slow, and awkward for mechanics doing volume of work, or if you want to just quickly throw your bike in a stand for a gear check.

The seat post mounted stands are larger (generally, sometimes, but not always less stable, but far quicker and easier to use. Downsides depend on the model, but generally: Less stability, and more difficulty working on an aero bike due to frame and seat post shapes not fitting in the clamp.

Aero bikes are where the BB mounted stands excel, and are the primary and most useful quality that they have and why we have 2 in our workshop. If your frame doesn't work in a seat post clamp based stand, they are your best option. FWIW, I've used the Park PRS-20 and 21, and the Tacx Spider Team. The Tacx is more stable but a far larger footprint. The park has better UX design, more user friendly position swaps, and things like that.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Main reason I'm thinking of a BB stand is that my seat post stand won't hold my newer bikes securely due to geometry.

Comment: That is the primary and most useful quality that they have. If your frame doesn't work in a seat post clamp based stand, they are your best option. FWIW, I've used the Park PRS-20 and 21, and the Tacx Spider Team. The Tacx is more stable but a far larger footprint. The park has better UX design.

Comment: Thanks. I'm leaning towards the PRS-20. Also considering the Topeak Prep Stand Max and the Tacx Spider.

Comment: I'm currently using the Tacx Spider Team at home. I like it a lot. I haven't seen the Topeak, so no info there. The Park is what I use for events, like when our shop goes to Abu Dhabi International Triathlon for the week in March. Easier to switch bikes, and when you have a large number of aero bikes, that is important.

Comment: I'm taking a look at the Tacx today. Turns out that a LBS has them in stock. ;~) Yay! Anyway, I can get my old Park stand to hold my bikes for really minor adjustments; but, I need to overhaul my main road bike and the old stand just doesn't work any more for major work. Thanks for the tip...I could potentially have a new repair stand this afternoon.

Comment: The bike is now sitting on the Tacx Spider Team. ;~)

Comment: :) Nice. Congratulations.